# PyQt4: Which one of these would be better/more correct? (Notepad++ clone)

Tags: python, oop, pyqt4, procedural-programming

I'm making a super simple Notepad++ clone in Python/PyQt4, and I'm wondering which of these options of storing editor tab data:

OPTION 1: I have a class called QQCodeTab, which stores the current Qsci.QsciScintilla instance for the current tab, the file path, current language, etc. These are mapped to tab indexes by a dict.

OPTION 2: Same as OPTION 1, but cut out the class and store everything in a dict instead (example: `{1: {"scintilla": <blah>, "filepath": "C:/File/whatevs.py"}, "language": "python"}`)

My code comments can explain it better.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qsci

class QQCodeEditor(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.new_tab()
        self.new_tab()
        # Option 1: Maps index to tab object
        # Option 2: Maps index to dict of options
        self.tab_info = {}

    def new_tab(self):
        scin = Qsci.QsciScintilla()
        index = self.addTab(scin, "New Tab")

    def get_tab_info(self, index):
        # Returns QQCodeTab object
        return self.tab_info[index]

    def save(self, index):
        # Option 2: Save dialog boc and file system stuff goes here
        pass

class QQCodeTab(object):
    def __init__(self, scintilla, editor):
        self.scintilla = scintilla
        self.editor = editor

    def save(self):
        # Option 1: Save dialog box and file system stuff goes here
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering whether to use a class of dictionary, you probably want a `namedtuple`. That gives you the simplicity of a `dict` with the attribute syntax of a class:

```
from collections import namedtuple

FooBar = namedtuple("FooBar", ["these", "are", "the", "attributes"])

FooBar(123, 324, the=12, attributes=656).these
#>>> 123
```